# is it possible to view json data posted from python api to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, rest, json-api

I have two projects on python and ruby on rails.

I want to send a random data from python as json data through api post
now,

is it possible to receive it on Ruby on rails and parse the data and store it in my ruby on rails database?

**Note**: data in python is dynamic data and not saved anywhere sending as it is receving from socket by converting into json and posting through api.

Comment: Yes, create RoR api, and catch and save it.

Comment: i have RoR api. python project posting the json data to RoR. how to catch that data in RoR?

Comment: From the params

Comment: @jvillian can u send syntax?

Comment: Add to your question what you see in your server log when your python app calls your RoR API.

Comment: @sriharisairamVentrapragada show me your routes and controller how looks that RoR api. share come code )))